# want to send email with url,it is working but it is redirecting me to another url i.e host/projectname/site/login

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

```
public function actionRequestPasswordReset()
{
$model = new UserSignup();
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
$email = $model->email;
$row = UserSignup::find()->where( ['email' => $email])->exists();       
if($row != 1)
{
Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'User does not exist.');
}
else{
$user = UserSignup::find()->where([
'email'=>$model->email
])->one();  
$randnkey = rand();
if(!empty($user)){
$template=" <a href=''> click here to verify your email address.</p>
Regards,
The NaijaLoving App Team";
$email = \Yii::$app->mailer->compose() 
->setTo($user->email)
//->setFrom([\Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => \Yii::$app->name . ' 
robot'])
->setFrom("info@gmail.com")
//->setSubject('Signup Confirmation')->setTextBody("Click this link ")
->setHtmlBody(
"<table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style='background:#065e52;'>
<img src='/naija_loving/frontend/web/image/logo.png'/>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div class=email-area style='margin-top:20px;'>
<div class='container email-box' style='background:#E3E3E3; padding:40px;'>
<div class='email-prgp'>
<p>Hi ".$user->username.",</p> 
<p>Your Username is ".$user->username." and to reset Password click on below 
link 
</p>".\yii\helpers\Html::a('confirm',Yii::$app->urlManager-
>createAbsoluteUrl(['remail/remail','id'=>$user->u_id,'key'=>$randnkey]))."
</p>
<br/></div>
<div class='lowr-email-prgph' style='margin-top: 20px;box-sizing: border-
box;'>
<p>Regards,<br>The NaijaLoving App Team</p></div></div></td></tr><tr><td>
<div class='email-footer-box' style='margin:0 auto; text-align:center; 
background:#065e52; padding:10px;color:#fff;'><p style='line-height:23px;'>
<a href='#' style='color:aqua'>Support@naijaloving.com</a><br>Follow 
us<br>fb twitter youtube</p></div></td></tr></tbody></table>")->send();
if($email){  
Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success',$user->username);
}
} else {
Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Sorry, we are unable to reset 
password for the provided email address.');
}
}
}
return $this->render('requestPasswordResetToken', [
'model' => $model,
]);
}
```

this code is for reset password link i want to redirect on button click to 
  remail/remail... but it is redirecting to host/site/login , is it any thing 
  wrong in code, I have written some custom code for sending email

Comment: See if there is accessControl filter in your RemailController allowing only logged users for every action.

Comment: no this is the process of forget password when clicking on forget password it redirects to reset password for it you have to write email and this will send email to your email account and then provided link will redirect to remail this link is not redirecting me to desired path

Comment: can you post the controller code pls

Comment: If you are pointing users to `remail/remail` and they are redirected to `site/login` it usually means there is access control filter in the controller set to prevent guests to run the action.

Comment: public function behaviors()
{
return [
'access' => ['class' => AccessControl::className(),
'only' => ['logout', 'signup'],
'rules' => [
[
'actions' => ['signup'],
'allow' => true,
'roles' => ['?'],
],
[
'actions' => ['logout'],
'allow' => true,
'roles' => ['@'],
],
],
],
'verbs' => [
'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
'actions' => [
'logout' => ['post'],
],
],
];
}  are you talking about this filter

Comment: @shikha are you sure this is behaviors() from RemailController and not SiteController?

Comment: ohh thank you @bizley i noticed my mistake in RemailController i had applied session there

Answer (score 0):

First of i suggest you to use mail template for sending mails. This way is not good practice.
Create a variable for anchor tag href i.e.

```
    $verifyLink = Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['/remail/remail',
'id'=>$user->u_id,'key'=>$randnkey]);
```

then use this variable to at anchor tag href attribute with `target = "_blank"`.